# Last article Widget with text preview and more button

Tags: plugins, widgets

I tried to use the last article widget from Wordpress and from my theme (deCanto last article).

The first one only shows me a link with the heading, the last one shows me the complete article!

But both cannot provide me the function I would like. The five last articles should be displayed on the start page. There should be a heading, date and an excerpt (e.g. first 200 words) from the article. Below there should be a "More" button with which the user comes to the full article.

> **Heading**
>
> 28th March 2012
>
> Lorem Ipsum Dolor Sit Amet ....
>
> More

Which widget can provide me such functionality? In the plugin directory there are too much results ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems that the article "How do I display read more buttons?" from http://themeshift.com/docs/read-more/ does the trick.

You have to place the more button in the article and define yourself when the break should be.